Why do voters buy political narratives?

Political narrative


Political narrative is a term used in the humanities and political sciences to describe the way in which storytelling can shape fact and effect understandings of reality.

In essence, political narratives are lies fed to voters to persuade them.
May I give some examples?

In the last term (2016) of Trump, his primary narrative was China is robbing us and his secondary narrative was illegal immigrants are destroying us. In this term (2024), the secondary narrative has become the primary narrative. In the meantime, the USA is suffering from hundreds of real issues, like: mass shooting, expensive healthcare, expensive education, drug addictions, crumbling mass transit, absence of adequate railway lines, etc.

Since 2014, Modi's political narrative has been Muslims are a threat to India's existence. In the meantime,

Modi's financial allies, like Gautam Adani, have been robbing the Indian economy to death.

In India, 77% of the country's total wealth is concentrated in the hands of the richest 10% of the population - in 2017 alone, 73% of the wealth generated went to the top 1%, while the bottom half of the population—approximately 670 million people—saw their wealth grow by just 1%.

50% of India’s GDP comes from just 13 districts of the country, leaving the remaining 774 districts to account for the other half. This stark imbalance is a textbook example of uneven growth.

Every 17 minutes, a rape case is officially reported in India. The unrecorded cases, however, are believed to be far more frequent—possibly as high as 17 every minute.

Indian court system has 58.4 million pending cases as of August 2024. The Supreme Court of India has 82,308 pending cases as of June 2024.




Why do voters buy political narratives and thereby fall into the traps of politicians?

This is just a flimsy frame work for you to write about the policies that you dislike.  There's no real question here.  Some people believe the narrative some don't. Not every story is a lie but if I give you narratives that you happen to think are true you'll just deny they are narratives and claim that they are just honest telling of the facts.  So vtc for that reason

Is there any reason why one would expect people to "consider political narratives as lies"?

The question is unclear. What does it mean to consider narratives as lies exactly? Surely voters don't believe everything they are told, so where is the problem? This question could dive more into what voters are supposedly doing wrong and could do better.

IMHO this is a valid and interesting question. It does require some expertise or at least reflection, rather than googling up a quote or a political statement. Vote to reopen.

TBH this is at heart a decent question even though @JamesK is kind of right in that it's formed as a sort of rant.

"In essence, political narratives are lies to brainwash voters." No. A political narrative is analogous the choice between terms like "undocumented migrant" vs. "illegal alien". Two narratives can be opposed without either being false. Your own examples about India show that you are really more concerned with narratives focusing on the wrong things, but it's not a "lie" for Modi to claim that something else is more important than the things you think are important; importance is subjective.

Your use of the word "brainwash" (as opposed to "persuade") is also part of a political narrative, the narrative being that too many voters aren't intelligent or critical enough to make good informed decisions. That narrative also isn't really a "lie", because "too many" and "enough" and "good" are all subjective. But ask yourself how you were persuaded that persuasion is akin to brainwashing, and you will understand a bit better why persuasion works.

Your question also pushes a narrative that Modi uses prejudice against Muslims to distract from real issues affecting India. You probably wrote it expecting people to agree that that is what Modi is doing, so you can also consider your own rhetorical techniques as an example of why people can be persuaded by political narratives.

It is hard to take a question seriously with the phrase "financial goons". Politics is the business of convincing. Nothing more and nothing less. How that convincing is done - words, government programs / promises, guns or something else - is the interesting part. Treating the community as incapable of deciphering a rant isn't really a question, IMHO.

They are a form of marketing.  Google "story marketing books" and you'll see many marketing authors recommend sticking to simple stories that already resonate with the target audience.  What if, say, you were to condense global warming concerns to a simple narrative.  Would it be incorrect to use that approach to connect to voters?  You certainly don't want to be throwing scientific research raw at them.  In this case, the narratives you are quoting are being used because the public is already predisposed to be swayed by them.  If not, they'd switch to other narratives.

Narratives can be used in different ways. Some are lies.
The human mind is predisposed to form chaotic sensory impressions into coherent stories. On the whole this is an evolutionary advantage, but it can make people see patterns where there are none. Compare the Rorschach test.
A political narrative is the attempt to suggest a desired interpretation of a collection of facts to the voter.

Consider "the foreign government is raising unfair barriers to trade, therefore we need to introduce punitive taxes -- vote for me to make that happen" vs. "other countries have managed to raise consumer protection standards, why can't our goverment do the same -- vote for me to make that happen." Both narratives might fit the same set of facts. Which one is "right" depends on the political view if those regulation are necessary consumer protection or if industry and consumers should be free from government meddling.
Consider "we have a shortage of affordable housing, and X percent of the housing is used by illegal immigrants -- vote for me to throw them out" vs. "we have a shortage of affordable housing, and X percent of the construction workers are illegal immigrants -- vote for me to regularize their status and keep them in." Which one is "right" depends very much on the end state one desires for society, and again there are different legitimate views.

By telling a narrative, a political speaker presents facts, interpretations, and values and it is important for the voter to understand values and interpretations, not just facts. Facts change from case to case, values should be more enduring.

A narrative is somewhat like a slogan that sounds good and reinforced what the person hearing it already believes or wants to believe e.g. there is a political narrative that Trump wants to deport American citizens, which is false. However, to many leftists who religiously believe orange man bad it reinforces their position that they hold and makes them feel good inside. It requires no critical thinking or skepticism and makes the people validated about their preconceived notions.
In your examples, illegals bring good and bad to the economy, so some people benefit while others suffer (mostly the native working class suffers and the elites benefit, see my answer here). So to a native day laborer who has to compete against illegals for work, this political narrative makes their day-to-day existence easier.
Similarly, for some Hindu nationalists, this political fiction is useful because it gives them an easy outlet to scapegoat i.e. Muslims instead of the elites who are exploiting them.

Is "Trump wants to deport American citizens" really a narrative pushed by any relevant mainstream media critics or political opponents of Trump? When I do a web search for "Trump wants to deport American citizens", then I receive plenty of news reports, but all of them talking only about deporting "illegal immigrants", "undocumented immigrants" or "criminal immigrants", but none that talk about him wanting to deport citizens. Can you find a better example that is actually widely used by relevant people?

A good source could be a fact checking site like politifacts. You could, for example, use this false narrative pushed by Kamala Harris about Trump or this false narrative pushed by Trump about Kamala Harris

@Philipp https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/us/tom-homan-u-turn-on-deporting-us-citizens/ar-AA1uqOXB?ocid=msedgntp&pc=HCTS&cvid=ae8db42e0a5a4d9e88d41b9069ebff38&ei=20

The article is about Tom Homan, not Donald Trump. And if the article is pushing any particular narrative, then that Homan is not clear about what he really wants to do.

@Philipp the article demonstrates how the mass media pushes a false narrative by lying that Trump (Homan is an appointee of Trump thus he speaks for Trump) wants to deport American citizens and in that article saying that Homan-Trump reverses course, whereas the truth is that it was never that case, Trump doesn't want to deport American citizens. Homan was asked if there is a way to deport criminal illegal immigrants without separating families, he said the families can leave all together. Read the article I linked fully and you will see this is 100% a fabricated narrative to demonize Trump.

@Philipp Politifact?!?!?! Bias in Fact Checking?: An Analysis of Partisan Trends Using PolitiFact Data  "there is a heterogeneity in their relative ratings of Democrats and Republicans that may suggest the presence of partisanship"  There's a lot more out there if you have the stones to actually look.... PolitiFact Quietly Retracts ‘Pants On Fire’ Lab Leak Fact Check

@Philipp Who fact checks the fact checkers? Over-reliance on fact checker puts you in the exact same position as completely ignoring fact checking entirely. Most fact checking sites are worse than tabloids, to be honest. They're filled with their own interpretations and analysis, which makes them their own political narrative. Even look at the two articles you linked. One of them they literally admit Harris did say one of the things Trump said she said, but the fact checkers decided it was false because they added the qualifier that it doesn't count because she wasn't VP when she said it.

@DavidS the main diff between "fact checking" and a "regular-ass article" is that fact checking explicitly cites all their sources used to draw a conclusion.

I don't necessarily think "political narratives" and "stories" imply an engineered work of fiction, although they can be.
China robbing the US
It's not quite true that China has "robbed" the US economy. It is more the case that US free-trade liberals have sold the US economy to China in exchange for profits.
But from the perspective of voters, they are less concerned with the means by which the US economy has transferred to China, only that it has done, and axiomatically the means by which it has occured must be illegitimate, because the means by which an illegitimate goal is achieved are never themselves legitimate means.
So the important aspect of the story is true - that the US economy is gone to China - even if it is dressed up rhetoric that is not liable to evoke a fully accurate impression of all that has occurred.
Trump is the only major political figure arguing robustly for tariffs, and thereby defying the very tenets of free-trade liberals who for a while have controlled both parties, so whereas the voters may have opted for someone telling a more accurate picture about how the US economy was lost to China and promising tariffs, for now Trump is the one resounding best with the views of the electorate.
Illegal immigration
The majority of electorates tend to be opposed to immigration by default, with only the salience of the issue varying over time.
Again the liberals who control politics, and who want to attack settled workers using imported and unorganised foreign labour, usually spend billions on manufacturing public opinion (especially amongst a minority who can be influenced), and nobbling politicians to ensure they obey liberal tenets regardless of what the electoral majority wants.
Many liberal politicians openly try to circle their own wagons to avoid a "slippery slope to the right" or other ideas about the situation which have, at their core, the fear that if they talk to the electorate about certain things or attribute higher priority to democratic influence than their own liberal ideology, the electorate may want more of those things rather than less.
So in that context where there is huge latent demand for immigration controls, again Trump is simply the only one seriously opposing immigration and sounding negative about it. Again, this simply resounds best with the electorate who want an end to immigration.
The vast majority of people don't care what is said to be good for the economy overall, or what effect immigration has on that, but about what is good for them as settled citizens of that country or the people around them who they consider to be like them.
Conclusion
If you see these cases as electorates simply being promised what they already wanted in an environment where politicians are consistently defying the electorate, then there is no basis for saying that people are routinely preferring lies in the form of "political narratives".
The actual dysfunctions of democracy largely arise from the rich-controlled media pumping lies constantly - not necessarily fully-informed electors wrongly believing them - and from using wealth to manipulate democratic processes in ways that stop the truth even being told sufficiently frequently by politicians for people to be familiar with it and to have the options on the ballot to express their judgment.
Most people have been rejecting the lies told by politicians for decades, by boycotting the ballot itself, to the point where most Western governments are elected by illegitimate minorities.

"The majority of electorates tend to be opposed to immigration by default" - citation needed.

@F1Krazy, consider this for example for the US: https://www.pewresearch.org/politics/2018/06/28/shifting-public-views-on-legal-immigration-into-the-u-s/. It's a few years old, but increases in migration have always been opposed by majorities in the US. That's consistent with my broad impression of people's everyday attitudes. Consider this for the UK: https://migrationobservatory.ox.ac.uk/resources/briefings/uk-public-opinion-toward-immigration-overall-attitudes-and-level-of-concern/
